# switch and case with fall-through, odd behaviour

Tags: c

I wrote the following code and I don't seem to why its behaving this way, can you help me, simple the code request from user to enter grade between 1 and 100, if user entered value greater than 100, the code prompt the user to try again, the odd behavior is when the user at his second entry, he entered again value greater than 100, the code evaluate result as Grade A, why its doing that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int get_grade(void){
int grade;
scanf ("%3d",&grade);
return grade;
}

int main (){
int grade=0;
printf ("please Enter your Grade \n");
grade=get_grade();
switch (grade){
    case 101 ... 999 :
    printf ("the score is out of 100 and you entered %d, please enter new Grade :",grade);
    grade=get_grade();
    // we removed break to continue with next case, this step is called fall through in programming
    case 80 ... 100:
    printf ("your grade is A %d\n",grade);
    break;
    case 60 ... 79:
    printf("your grade is B \n");
    break;
    case 50 ... 59:
    printf ("your grade is C \n");
    break;
    default:
    printf ("we consider you failed \n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not standard C.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which compiler allows this switch?

Comment: @Lundin `gcc` as an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment in the code you posted specifies, there is fall through from the first case to the second case in the switch block. Therefore, after calling `get_grade()` for the second time, the code proceeds into the second case.

Comment: so it will not check the condition of the next case, just continue no matter what is the condition

Comment: @abdelrahman, yes, consider using `do {grade=get_grade();} while (grade > 100);` instead of `grade=get_grade();` before the `switch` and remove the `case 101 ... 999 :` block